# Cannot resolve symbol 'cell'

Tags: android

I am following one of Mark Murphy's tutorials about a Selection Grid. I have tried just copy/paste (after typing it out) to check I wasn't making any errors but I still get the "cell" word in red.  the imports are all as they should be.
Here is the code. 
The problem is in the line `g.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.cell, items));`

I tried adding compile lines into the build.gradle dependencies. didn't help.

```
public class GridDemo extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private TextView selection;
    private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
            "sit", "amet",
            "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
            "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
            "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
            "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
        GridView g=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        g.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.cell, items));
        g.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        selection.setText(items[position]);
    }
}
```

Comment: My code looks like it is not formatted.  I'm not sure how to post and make it formatted.

Comment: I fixed it. Make sure you read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Where you have defined a `cell` layout?

Comment: Ok, thanks everybody, I have worked out the problem.  I should not have posted so hastily. Although it has been bothering me for several hours.

Answer (score 0):

One method you should be create cell.xml in layout folder or you need to replace this code

```
   g.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it is from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.1/Selection/Grid).

`R.layout.cell` is a reference to [a `cell` layout resource](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.1/Selection/Grid/app/src/main/res/layout/cell.xml) that will be used to set up the contents of an individual cell of the `GridView`. You will need that layout resource in your project, or modify the Java code to avoid using that layout resource.